# A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed on MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to display the grid on the view and it's giving me an error on the gird. This is the view

```
@{var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 20,
      selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
     grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
     ViewBag.Title = "Data results";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Results";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_InternalLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Data Results</h2>
<div id="gridContent">
    <p class="text-success">@ViewBag.Result</p>
    <p class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ReportTable", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @grid.GetHtml(

   tableStyle: "webGrid2 ReportTable",
                         headerStyle: "header",
                         alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                         selectedRowStyle: "select",
                         columns: grid.Columns(
                                  grid.Column("Number", "Destination", canSort: false),
                                  grid.Column("Received", "Receive Time", canSort: false),
                                  grid.Column("Message", "Message", canSort: false),
                                  grid.Column("Resubmit", format: @<text><input class="chkbox" id="resubChkbx" name="ResubmitChkbx" type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" /></text>)
                        ))}
</div>
```

And this is the controller

```
public ActionResult ReportTable()
        {
            return View("ReportTable");

}
```

The error code that I get is the following:

> A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed

And highlights @grid.Gethtml

Comment: you haven't told the grid where the data is coming from

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the source of WebGrid.

```
public ActionResult ReportTable()
{
  var yourmodel=new List<YouModelType>(); /// generate model
  return View(yourmodel);//// pass model parameter to view
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...but why a list and not a new model?

Comment: @jacopk. because WebGrid expects  `IEnumerable<Object>`